# C#: alternative to exists or getfirstordefault

Tags: c#, collections, .net-3.0

I have a class

```
class Person {

 int Age;
 string Name;
}

List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();

 pList.Exists(p=> p.Name == "testName");  <-- need an alternative for this.
```

I'm using .net 3.0.

As such I don't have access to `getFirstOrDefault` method.

The `Exists` method throws an exception for null values, but I don't want to interrupt my program flow; is there any other alternative?

I don't have `Any` or `Linq` available either.

Comment: What do you have?  Do you have an array, a list, an `IEnumerable`, or what?  What is inside of that collection?  What are you trying to do with that collection?  Show some sample input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) should be fine - you just need to handle the possibility of `p` being `null`.

```
bool nameExists = pList.Exists(p => p != null && p.Name == "testName");
```

Alternatively, make sure that your list doesn't contain any `null` references to start with - that may well make all kinds of things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool nameExists = pList.Any(p=>p.Name == "testName");
```

or (if you won't use `Any` ):

```
bool nameExists = pList.Select(p=>p.Name).Contains("testName");
```